# How can i change path to Laravel project?

Tags: frameworks, crudbooster

Change web root path to a website with crudbooster and Laravel

so, i have a website and the cms behind was done with crudbooster and larvel. when the website was created, the path for it was: /webroot/domainA/site/site/ 
I want to move this to /webroot/domainB/site/site but when i`m changing the path, whole website is down and not working unless i change back the original path to /webroot/domainA

Where can i change the path of the website to be the one I needed?

- domainA - developer server
- domainB - client server

This was a fiver.com project, and the person who did it not responding to my emails.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the .env file and change the APP_URL